# Basic questions about IP addressing/Networks/Remote MySQL database connection

Tags: mysql, networking, network-programming

I have a  couple network/msyql/IP address questions if you guys wouldn't mind answering if you know them.

I have 2 IP addresses for my computer, the 1 when i type "ipconfig" in command prompt(172.xxx.xxx.xxx), and the other 1 when i type "ip address" into google(108.xxx.xxx.xxx). I would like to clarify which each of these IP's are.

Is the address "172.xxx.xxx.xxx" the public WAN IP address that my ISP gave me?

Is the address "108.xxx.xxx.xxx" the private LAN IP address that my router assigned to me?

The reserved private address ranges of 
10.0.0.0, 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0, 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0, 192.168.255.255
have a total sum of 17million address(16m+1m+64k). Are these addresses the ones that the IANA gives to ISP's which they give to each company/home? And if they are, then why are they named "private" in wiki? I though private IP's were IP's behind a router in a LAN.

I have a c++ program with mysql connector that connects to a mysql database on one of my home LAN computers through my private(WAN?) IP(172.xxx.xxx.xxx). So my question is will this program still connect to my database if i run it on computers outside of my LAN?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: I have no idea what you just said...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP address you see from google is the public IP address, the address given to you via your modem.  The other address is your private IP address.

Access to your mySQL DB is only avail when connected in the private network.  You would have to setup port/IP forwarding on your router to allow access to your mySQL DB, you'd also need a static IP address given to you by your provider.

With this setup you'd connect to your mySQL DB via the public IP (static) address and your router would forward requests to your mySQL machine.

Comment: Do i already have a static IP address given by my provider? Or is this an additional request everyone has to make?

Comment: your public IP is dynamic (DHCP) and can cahnge, you could setup the routing/port forwarding without the static IP but your public IP will change eventually unless you $PAY$ for the static.  Please give credit if this answered your Q...  =)